# (Second) derivation of J.R. Gott's probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to digest J.R. Gott's [1993 Nature paper](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v363/n6427/pdf/363315a0.pdf) describing how the Copernican principle can be applied to estimate the duration of our species (and many other neat things). The paper opens with a section he calls the "Delta t" argument which I found very straightforward. Then he restates the problem more formally in the next section, rederiving the same result as before. I'm not able to follow his math in equation 6. Because of the publication firewall, I'll copy the relevant lines here.

> Let $r_1$ and $r_2$ be independent random numbers each distributed uniformly over the interval [0, 1]. For a given species alive today,
>   $$ r_1^{t_f/t_p} = r_2 $$
>   Let $Y>0$ be a constant
>   $$ P\left( [ t_f/t_p] > Y \right) = \int_0^1 r_1^Y\,dr_1$$

Clearly statistics is not my strong suit, but I have the impression that this calculation would involve finding $P\left( r_1^Y - r_2 > 0 \right)$ and don't see the connection to the integral given. I thought I could calculate this by applying [this information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29#Related_distributions) that if $X$ has a standard uniform distribution, then $Z=X^n$ also has a standard uniform distribution, to calculate $P\left( r_1^Y - r_2 > 0 \right)$ using summation of two independent random variables, but I am obviously bungling it because in that case the $Y$ seems to disappear. Any help appreciated!

Comment: "if X has a standard uniform distribution, then Z=Xn also has a standard uniform distribution" Not at all (and not what WP says).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might recognize your setting as the following:

> Let $R$ and $S$ be i.i.d. uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. Define a third random variable $A$ by $R^A=S$. Then $A\gt0$ almost surely and the density of $A$ is $f_A(a)=1/(a+1)^2$ on $a\gt0$.

To show this, note that, for every $a\gt0$, the event $[A\gt a]$ is $[R^A\lt R^a]=[S\lt R^a]$ hence $P[A\gt a]=P[S\lt R^a]$. Note that $R^a\lt1$ almost surely hence the fact that $P[S\lt s]=s$ for every $s$ in $(0,1)$ shows that $P[S\lt R^a]=E[R^a]=\int\limits_0^1r^a\mathrm dr$. Finally, $P[A\gt a]=1/(a+1)$ for every $a\gt0$, which yields the density of $A$ indicated above.

An interesting feature of the distribution of $A$ is that, by construction and by the symmetry of the distribution of $(R,S)$, the distributions of $A$ and $1/A$ coincide.

Comment: I would vote this up, but evidently I need something called a reputation first. You're absolutely right that I was way off on interpreting the wikipedia page mentioned in the original question. Your explanation was very helpful - thank you!